# Gridster add custom width, height, left and top

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am working on a project in which we have widgets of different width and height. Dimension of widgets are

```
Width x Height
 776  x  461
 375  x  232
 776  x  323
 375  x  323
 576  x  573
 576  x  271
 1177 x  513
```

I checked all styles of grister but these width and height do not exist in gridster style. Please give me solution, how can I make widgets of these dimensions. Another question, how can I make it responsive ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I get its answer. I just make

```
autogenerate_stylesheet = false
```

and then i write my own style